# How to do action for each result in array?

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some recipes using [recipe-scrapers](https://github.com/hhursev/recipe-scrapers) and Python. In the code below I am trying to add multiple url's to scrape and have the data into a CSV file in the end. The code also *checks if the domain is in the list of site supported.* Unfortunately this is not working.

The error displayed is :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I think it is because the code is wrong, the

```
domain = urlparse(site).netloc
```

breaks the whole thing.

However it does work with only one site domain.

```
import csv
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_me, SCRAPERS
from urllib.parse import urlparse

site = ['https://www.website.com/recipe/246439/poulet--poulet-solange',
        'https://www.website.com/recipe/244688/-dauphinois-white-vin/?',
        'https://www.website.com/recipe/223506/--white/']

if site != '':

    for i in site:
        # Now check to see if the domain is in the SCRAPERS dictionary...
        domain = urlparse(site).netloc
        domain = domain.replace("www.", "")
        if domain in SCRAPERS:

           scraper = scrape_me(site)
           title = scraper.title()
           total_time = scraper.total_time()
           yields = scraper.yields()
           ingredients = scraper.ingredients()
           instructions = scraper.instructions()
           image = scraper.image()

           #print(f'Title: {title}')
           #print(f'Total Time: {total_time}')
           #print(f'Servings: {yields}')
           # print(f'Ingredients: {ingredients}')
           #print('Ingredients:\n')
           #for ing in ingredients:
           #    print(f'    {ing}')
           #print(f'\nInstructions: {instructions}')
           #print(f'Image URL: {image}')
        #else:
             #print('\nSorry, that website is not currently supported.')
             # to do : export data to csv . change words/synonyms. Re-export csv to create wordpress posts

with open('test.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as recipes_file:
    for i in site :
        recipe_writer = csv.writer(recipes_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        recipe_writer.writerow([title, total_time, ingredients, instructions, image])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but as far as I can see you just have to use `i` instead of `site` (you are looping trough the list of sites after all).

`domain = urlparse(site).netloc`
 and 
`scraper = scrape_me(site)` at least.

EDIT:

In addition to your comment - you are actually saving the last result 3 times since you are doing it in a separate for loop. The way to fix this would be to restructure your code and put everything in one for loop:

Before you start the loop:
`with open('test.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as recipes_file:`

Inside the loop:
`recipe_writer = csv.writer(recipes_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`
`recipe_writer.writerow([title, total_time, ingredients, instructions, image])`

Comment: Thanks, that was a major first thing to fix. However now the data of the first url in the array is repeated on each row ( so 3 rows ) , instead of having the other data of the other array url's.

Comment: this was it, and I understand the logic. Thank you very much for your clear help !